# how to impliment flex with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, css, flexbox

I am using a panel to display list of user and applying flex with ng-repeat but it's not working plz help me do this and i also want to implement scroll for this panel

[image: this is image of panel]

this is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="Employee">
  <label  class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary panel-default" id="panel3">
      <div class="panel-heading swpanel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" href="" class="collapsed">Mobile EmployeeList:</a>
        </h4>
      </div>                        
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse col-xs-6">
        <div layout="row" layout-wrap flex >                                                
          <div flex="50" ng-repeat="item in mobileEmployeeList">                        
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="exists(item.rep_id, selectedEmployeeList)" ng-click="toggle(item.rep_id, selectedEmployeeList)">
              {{ item.rep_name }} 
              <span ng-if="exists(item.rep_id, selectedEmployeeList)"></span>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>                    
      </div>                        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you create a plunker,http://plnkr.co

Comment: arnt you using bootstrap ?? and flex is angular-material attribute

Comment: Add the controller code for the array - mobileEmployeeList

Comment: mobileEmployeeList is coming form database  it contains array data like:[Object { rep_name="sankar",  rep_id=14}, Object { rep_name="Mahadev",  rep_id=16},Object { rep_name="deleteUser",  rep_id=45}]

Comment: @MohsinMuzawar so we can not use flex in bootstrap?, and any alternative is there plz

Answer (score 0):

it could be like that:

```html
<md-content md-padding>
  <md-list id="users-list" class="flex flex-col">

    <ul class="flex flex-row full-width" ng-repeat="user in mobileEmployeeList">
      <input flex="5" type="checkbox" ng-checked="exists(item.rep_id, selectedEmployeeList)" ng-click="toggle(item.rep_id, selectedEmployeeList)">{{ item.rep_name }}
      <span ng-if="exists(item.rep_id, selectedEmployeeList)"></span>

      <li flex="25" class="flex flex-col">{{user.name}}</li>
      <li flex="25" class="flex flex-col">{{user.username}}</li>
    </ul>
  </md-list>
</md-content>
```